# x1, y1 and radius are given - can anything be assumed about x2, y2?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I have a list of lat/lng coordinates. Given the coordinates x1, y1, and a radius r -- is there anything I can assume about the coordinates that fall within the radius of x1, y1? For example, can I compute a min and max value for x2 and y2?

Basically, I want to get from the list of lat/lng coordinates all those that are within the radius of x1, y1. Normally, I would use the haversine formula to compute the distance between the two points and see if it falls within the radius. However, I do not have that option at this point due to the programming environment I am currently in (this is for a website that returns a list of companies within an area).

Comment: About the most you can say (assuming that $(x_2, y_2)$ is inside that circle) is that $x_1 - r \leq x_2 \leq x_1+r$ and $y_1-r \leq y_2 \leq y_1+r$.  Any $(x_2, y_2)$ in the circle satisfies what I just said, but there are points that satisfy those requirements and are not in the circle.

Comment: If the area is small and not too close to the poles, you can consider it flat, and calculate an average distance for 0.1°. This is only an approximation, but it could be sufficent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_2$ and $y_2$ need to satisfy the following inequality:

$\sqrt {(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2} \leq r$